# What is the most inefficient sorting routine?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

For an array of integers, what is the least efficient way of sorting the array. The function should make progress in each step (eg no infinity loop). What is the runtime of that algorithm?

Comment: What do you count as "progress"?

Comment: sounds like homework ...

Comment: By progress I mean the loop invarient principle, or whatever makes sense to you. Also, not homework.

Comment: Randomly shuffle the array on every iteration. Check to see if it's sorted. Repeat until it is.

Comment: [Comparison of sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

Comment: @James, Nice. Ttat's the type of creativity I'm looking for.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, the runtime wouldn't be finite

Comment: How would this be useful outside of academia? I.e. How is this not homework?

Comment: @JamesAllardice aka, the [Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - That's the one! I knew it had a name but couldn't remember it. I particularly like the "Quantum Bogosort" described in that article :)

Comment: Crowd-source it.  Have one person each sort one item in the array.  By hand.  Consider it an asynchronous operation so each item will come back in an indeterminate order.  Continue until the array is sorted.  (Note that it doesn't have to be people.  Trained cats can probably be equally as ineffective.)

Comment: The Q is a lark, its too risky getting HW help here anyway.

Comment: I think, it would be better if you said you wanted least computationally efficient algorithm in terms of big O. Some may be worse than others in their memory efficiency which may significantly affect their real world (different memory access times, not too big input) performance IMO

Comment: And you should have probably asked about worst commonly used algorithm, see David Heffernan's answer.

Comment: something more, my non-answer on Bubble Sort: if not the worst, it is certainly one of the best known ugly algorithms I know. I have no idea why they teach it, maybe because it seems as a miracle that it even works in the end. I even got a question about BS (pun intended) at a job interview and they did not like that I'd laughed. :)

Comment: There are different sorting algorithms for long arrays, very random arrays, repetitive arrays, etc. Within reason different sorting algorithms are better in different situations which is why there isn't just one

Comment: @MarianP I agree completely. Always baffled me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [stupid sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) is surely the worst algorithm. It's not exactly an infinite loop but this approach has as worst case `O(inf)` and the avarage is `O(n × n!)`.

Answer (score 9):

There can be no least efficient algorithm for anything. This can easily be proved by contradiction so long as you accept that, starting from any algorithm, another equivalent but less efficient algorithm can be constructed.

Comment: good thinking. the kind of question needs more though over definition.

Comment: Where is the progress in each step?

Comment: @userunknown What do you mean by that?

Comment: From the question `The function should make progress in each step`. If you want to sort 1,4,3,2 ascending - I don't see how you can have more than 3 or 4 improving steps until it is sorted.

Comment: if you could reasonably define progress or improving steps then you may have a point. Can you make such a definition. The question certainly did not.

Answer (score 6):

[Bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) has average runtime of `O(n*n!)`, ouch.

Comment: Even better, it has a worst-case runtime of `O(infinity)` if the random number god hates your guts or if your PRNG just doesn't have to sequence of numbers it takes to get a sorted array.

Comment: @delnan The latter is more likely than not with any reasonably sized list of numbers.

Comment: Where is the progress in each step?

Answer (score 2):

The least efficiant algorithm I can think with a finite upper bound on runtime is permutation sort. The idea is to generate every permutation (combination) of the inputs and check if it's sorted.

The upper bound is O(n!), the lower bound is O(n) when the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(n!*n)` by generating all unqiue permutations and afterwards checking if the array is sorted.

Comment: Where is the progress in each step?

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate over all finite sequences of integers using diagonalization.
2. For each sequence, test whether it's sorted.
3. If so, test whether its elements match the elements in your array.

This will have an upper bound (first guess: O(n^(n*m)?).

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, normally we go for the fastest.

Find the highest and move it to a list. Repeat the previous step till the original list has only one element left. You are guaranteed O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

Bogosort is a worst sorting algorithm uses shuffle. But in another point of view it has low probability to sort array in one step :)

Comment: It has no guaranteed improvement per step.

Answer (score 0):

"Worstsort" has a complexity of [image: \Omega((n!^{(f(n))})^2)] where [image: n!^{(m)} = (...((n!)!)!...)! =] factorial of n iterated m times. The paper by Miguel A. Lerma can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1077v1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Bogobogo sort.It's like bogo sort,shuffles.But it creates auxiliary arrays,the first one is the same array others are smaller by 1 element compared to previous one.They can be removed as well.
It's average complexity is O(N superfactorial*n). It's best case is O(N^2). Just like bogo sort it has worst case of O(inf).